# Cannot get the list of album in Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

All,
I am a beginner in Facebook programming. My test project is a simple website which displays Facebook account information (only name and id) and the list of albums of that Facebook account. The problem is, after authentication, I can get the profile data, but I cannot get the album list.
Here is code to get the profile information:

```
    [FacebookAuthorize(LoginUrl = "~/Account/Login")]
    public ActionResult Profile()
    {
        var fbWebContext = FacebookWebContext.Current;
        if (fbWebContext.IsAuthorized())
        {
            try
            {
                var fb = new FacebookWebClient(fbWebContext);
                var token = fb.AccessToken;
                dynamic me = fb.Get("/me");
                ViewBag.Name = me.name;
                ViewBag.Id = me.id;
                ViewBag.AccessToken = token;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                {
                    fbWebContext.DeleteAuthCookie();
                    Session.Clear();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

and here is code to get the album list

```
    [FacebookAuthorize(LoginUrl = "~/Account/Login")]
    public ActionResult Album()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient(FacebookWebContext.Current);
        IDictionary<string, object> albums = fb.Get("me/albums") as IDictionary<string, object>;

        dynamic albumList = albums["data"];

        foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albumList)
        {
            if (ViewBag.Albums == null)
                ViewBag.Albums = new List<string>();
            ViewBag.Albums.Add(albumInfo.id);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

in above code, the item count of albumList always = 0.
Could you please help me to resolve this issue?
A minor note: my test website is a ASP.Net MVC3 web application written in C#.

Edit in response to Andy's answer:

In fact, I set lots of permissions but it still cannot get the album list. Here is code in my OAuth method.

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("permissions", "user_about_me,offline_access,user_photos,publish_stream");

dynamic tokenResult = oAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(code, parameters);
```

Note that I did try to replace ""permissions" by "scope" but still failed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you requested the `user_photos` permission? You need to request additional permissions during Authentication if you want to access additional user data.

See this [Facebook permissions page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) for more info.

If you are using the Facebook JavaScript SDK [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method then you can simply add the `user_photos` permission to the perms option:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    if (response.perms) {
      // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
      // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
    } else {
      // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
    }
  } else {
    // user is not logged in
  }
}, {perms:'user_photos'});
```

Hope this helps.